# Xamarin android development, scroll view 'scrollchange' event when attached to delegate throws runtime error?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My team is working on Xamarin Android Development. In a view I have a scrollView and i am using 'ScrollChange' event of scrollview to detect scroll movement and performing required actions. It works fine for my machine. But when i used the same code on another machine, i am getting run-time error as follows:

```
Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: mono.android.view.View_OnScrollChangeListenerImplementor
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending couple of hours, i make few changes to my code and now its working fine. Earlier I was using following code to attach the delegate.

```
ScrollView ScrollView1 = (ScrollView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ScrollView1);
            ScrollView1.ScrollChange += ScrollView1_ScrollChange;

 private void ScrollView1_ScrollChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollView scrollView = sender as ScrollView;

            double scrollingSpace = scrollView.GetChildAt(0).Height - scrollView.Height;

            if (scrollingSpace <= scrollView.ScrollY) // Touched bottom
            {
                // Do the things you want to do
                Toast.MakeText(this, "You have reached to the bottom!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
```

Now the above code was working on almost every machine but not on all the machine. Few machines throwing the error as mentioned above.
Then i altered the delegate method params as follows:

```
void ScrollView1_ScrollChange(object sender, View.ScrollChangeEventArgs e)
```

Now rest definition remains the same. Now this delegate works fine for every machine.

Comment: Nexus4(KitKat) on Xamarin Android Player still raises "Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: mono.android.view.View_OnScrollChangeListenerImplementor" when using delegate below.

    void _scrollView_ScrollChange(object sender, ScrollChangeEventArgs e)

Comment: Can you please mention the API Level of you device ?

Comment: @MasahikoMiyasaka please visit the following link
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1082055/Xamarin-Android-EventHandlers-for-ScrollView-for-E